# opennebula libvirt live migration failire

Tags: libvirt, opennebula

From the sunstone GUI I tried performing a live migration from luther to blackout but the migration failed. Kindly see below excerpt from oned.log. Thanks for assistance and leads in advance.

Wed Feb 12 13:15:34 2014 [VMM][I]: Successfully execute transfer manager driver operation: tm_premigrate.
Wed Feb 12 13:15:34 2014 [VMM][I]: ExitCode: 0
Wed Feb 12 13:15:34 2014 [VMM][I]: Successfully execute network driver operation: pre.
Wed Feb 12 13:15:35 2014 [VMM][I]: Command execution fail: /var/tmp/one/vmm/kvm/migrate 'one-4' 'blackout' 'luther' 4 luther
Wed Feb 12 13:15:35 2014 [VMM][E]: migrate: Command "virsh --connect qemu:///system migrate --live one-4 qemu+ssh://blackout/system" failed: error: unable to connect to server at 'blackout:49152': No route to host
Wed Feb 12 13:15:35 2014 [VMM][E]: Could not migrate one-4 to blackout
Wed Feb 12 13:15:35 2014 [VMM][I]: ExitCode: 1
Wed Feb 12 13:15:35 2014 [VMM][I]: Failed to execute virtualization driver operation: migrate.
Wed Feb 12 13:15:35 2014 [VMM][E]: Error live migrating VM: Could not migrate one-4 to blackout
Wed Feb 12 13:15:35 2014 [LCM][I]: Fail to live migrate VM. Assuming that the VM is still RUNNING (will poll VM).
Wed Feb 12 13:56:36 2014 [LCM][I]: New VM state is SAVE_STOP
Wed Feb 12 13:56:44 2014 [VMM][I]: ExitCode: 0

Comment: iptables was the culprit. simple stop or add ports 49152-49261 to firewall to perform successful migrations.

Answer (score 0):

iptables was the culprit. Simple turn of iptables or add libvirt default port ranges

Comment: live migration port ranges are 49152-49215